# How do I get error details from FBResult in Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Is there any way to get error details from the FB.API() call in the Facebook Unity SDK? This code

```
FB.API(
  query: "/me/achievements",
  callback: response => {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Error)) {
      Logger.LogError("FB ReportProgress Error: " + response.Error);
    } else {
      Logger.Log("FB ReportProgress response: " + response.Text);
    }
  },
  method: Facebook.HttpMethod.POST,
  formData: new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"achievement", url}}
);
```

logs "400 Bad Request" and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enable MonoDevelop's debugger:

- In MonoDevelop go to the Preferences, then `Unity > Debugger`
- Untick "Build project in MonoDevelop" and click OK
- `Run > Attach To Process...`
- Select `Unity Editor`, click OK

Then, set a breakpoint inside the callback. Select this line in your code and select `Run > New Breakpoint...`

```
Logger.LogError("FB ReportProgress Error: " + response.Error);
```

Then hit Play in Unity and trigger the error (breakpoint). It'll switch to MonoDevelop. Down in the `Locals` debug window (which should be in a tab somewhere, otherwise `View > Debug Windows > Locals`) expand the `FBResult` object. The actual error message (which I assume you're needing) can be found under `FBResult > data > responseHeaderString`.

More info on MonoDevelop debugging: http://unitygems.com/debugging-game-monodevelop/

Comment: Sorry, I see that you don't necessarily want just the error message. It's simply a case of moving the breakpoint up to the first line of your callback.